# Caching nested objects using Spring Cache?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, caching, spring-cache

I have 2 domain Objects `Price` and `Product` defined as below.

```
public class Price {
  private Long id;
  private Double basePrice;
  private Double tax;
  private Double maxRetailPrice;
}
```

```
public class Product {
  private Long id;
  private String title;
  private Price price;
}
```

I have defined the `Controller` method as below:

```
@GetMapping("{id}")
@Cacheable(value = "product-cache", key = "#id")
public Product getProductById(@PathVariable Long id) {
  // some implementation goes here.
}
```

Is there a possibility to cache both `product` and `price` separately with their respective `id` fields as the keys ?

Something like :

```
@GetMapping("{id}")
@Caching(cacheable = {
    @Cacheable(value = "product-cache", key = "#id"),
    @Cacheable(value = "price-cache", key = "???")
})
public Product getProductById(@PathVariable Long id) {
  // some implementation goes here.
}
```

How to store the `price` part of the `product` object into `price-cache` with key as `id` of the `price` object.

I have tried multiple ways and combinations using SpEL, but could not get it working.

If anyone has tried something like this please help me.

Thank you.

Comment: IMO, it is not easy to do it via directly annotation way, I can do it by accessing `price-cache` cache and storing it manually, but its a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

If you're returning a product object, may be you could try something like:

```
@GetMapping("{id}")
@Caching(cacheable = {
    @Cacheable(value = "product-cache", key = "#id"),
    @Cacheable(value = "price-cache", key = "#result.data.product.price.id")
})
public Product getProductById(@PathVariable Long id) {
  // some implementation goes here.
}
```

Comment: But wouldn't above will store `Product` object into `price-cache` with key as priceId?, similar to `product-cache` where key is productId and value is `Product`?

Comment: Oh you're right. I think you'll have to implement it yourself if you need to cache the nested object separately. In redis that would look something like:

 redisTemplate.opsForValue().set(priceKey,price);